# C program - confusing output

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that computes the value of a word by summing the values of its letters.

These are the letters and their corresponding value:

- 1 Point: A, E, I, L, N, O, R, S, T, U
- 2 Points: D, G
- 3 Points: B, C, M, P
- 4 Points: F, H, V, W, Y
- 5 Points: K
- 8 Points: J, X
- 10 Points: Q, Z

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch; int sum=0;

    printf("Enter a word: ");

    while ((ch=getchar())!='\n') {
        toupper(ch);
        if (ch== 'A' || ch== 'E' || ch== 'I' || ch== 'L' || ch== 'N' || ch== 'O' || ch== 'R' || ch== 'S' || ch== 'T' || ch== 'U')
            sum+=1;

        else if (ch== 'D' || ch== 'G')
            sum+=2;

        else if (ch=='B' || ch== 'C' || ch== 'M' || ch== 'P')
            sum+=3;

        else if (ch=='F' || ch== 'H' || ch== 'V' || ch== 'W' || ch== 'Y')
            sum+=4;

        else if (ch=='K')
            sum+=5;

        else if (ch=='J' || ch== 'X')
            sum+=8;

        else if (ch=='Q' || ch== 'Z')
            sum+=10;
    }
    printf("\nScrabble value: %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it prints "Scrabble value: 0". Seems like the program is skipping the while loop entirely, maybe I am not using getchar properly, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The points are the same points for each letter in the game scrabble.Is it so you are creating some program in connection with scrabble?

Comment: Yes, I am reading a book and creating this program was an exercise.

Comment: Thanks guys! I wasn't expecting answers so fast.

Comment: Then mark an answer as accepted by pressing the green tick mark beside the answer

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns `int`, and might return `EOF` rather than an actual character. I/O is tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `ch = toupper(ch);`

`toupper` does not modify it's argument.

And, while not in any way related to the issue, I would recommend using `switch` for code like  this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `toupper()`. The function does not alter your char directly, it returns the altered char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch; int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter a word: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        ch = toupper(ch);
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'L' || ch == 'N' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'R' || ch == 'S' || ch == 'T' || ch == 'U')
            sum += 1;
        else if (ch == 'D' || ch == 'G')
            sum += 2;
        else if (ch == 'B' || ch == 'C' || ch == 'M' || ch == 'P')
            sum += 3;
        else if (ch == 'F' || ch == 'H' || ch == 'V' || ch == 'W' || ch == 'Y')
            sum += 4;
        else if (ch == 'K')
            sum += 5;
        else if (ch == 'J' || ch == 'X')
            sum += 8;
        else if (ch == 'Q' || ch == 'Z')
            sum += 10;
    }
    printf("\nScrabble value: %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`toupper(ch);` computes the uppercase of ch but does nothing with it. Your code works fine with UPPERCASE input. With lowercase input you just need to change

```
toupper(ch);
```

to

```
ch = toupper(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the converted character to a variable it remains in the case in which it had been entered. 'toupper' is a function and to re-use the value it returns you must store a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Sentences may not be "loose" in a program, must be associated with others, in general with the assignment sign (=).
Change `ch = toupper(ch)` by `ch = toupper(ch)`